# Google app engine- Django- numpy pandas blaze

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, numpy

I am working on a project where I need to use numpy, pandas, balze for my application.

First I get error of libraries not found which I solved by creating a lib folder and got all the packages that are required.

Then I got error of numpy>> multiarray not found, tried everthing then degraded numpy to numpy==1.6.0 problem solved

Then I got error of pandas >> hashtable not found, and now I do not have any clue how to solve this. using pandas==0.10.0

Please somebody help me on how to get things done on GAE using django and all libraries.

The error can be seen in smacscience.appspot.com

Or if my approach is completely wrong please help me.

Please help me out!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you solve  how to make Pandas work in GAE ??

Answer (score 2):

Vendoring libraries (putting them in the lib/ folder) will only work for pure Python libraries, while numpy requires some system libraries. Instead, using numpy by adding this to app.yaml:

libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"

I am not sure about your Pandas problem, it may be related or not.

An alternative approach is to use App Engine Flexible, which is container-based, so you can install whatever you want. The tradeoff is that the deploys are slower and there's no free tier (since you must run at least one VM).

You can read my guide on using Django in App Engine Flexible here:

https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

And you can see a complete tutorial app on App Engine Flexible here:

https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app

with this approach, you can just add your dependencies to a requirements.txt and it should work similarly to local development.

Comment: I have created a virtual environment and created my app there. and installed the required packages inside the environment, then checked the django version by running the app and got "django verison 1.9" as output. Then I uploaded it in google sever there is hows "django-version 1.4". This means it is not working on my virtual environment.

Please help me where I am going wrong. I am using pycharm to upload my project.

in app.yaml 
I have made vm: true as well.